# Debug ServiceStack POST Request Deserialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servicestack

I have a use case where I am posting a complex object with an array member using jQuery. E.g.:

```
data: {
   obj1: obj1,
   arr1: [ ... ]
}
```

On the server I have implemented a ServiceStack service. The automatic request mapping on the server produces nulls for the request members, but if I extract the Request.GetRawBody(), and then use ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString, I get what I need.

It would be useful to debug the actual deserialization and see what is missing. Anyone know how to do this?

**Examples:**

**Pass in a flat object**
Define a simple request object with a few fields:

```
public class Request
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Make a jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  data: {
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
});
```

The call works, the server receives the object with "John Doe" name property.

**Pass object with child-object**

```
public class Request
{
  public Caller Caller { get; set; }
}

public class Caller
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then make a call from jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: {
    caller: {
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
  }
});
```

After the call, the "caller" property of the request on the service is "null", so this approach is not working.

**Conclusion**
In my original assessment I was referring to an object and array combination. I guess the problem is in getting a simple sub-object to serialize/deserialize. Does this means the concept is not supported, or am I passing the object in incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, hope the answer helps others. It turns out that $.ajax is sending the content type as form url encoded (which is clearly documented in the jQuery documentation, I had just missed it):
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Setting the contentType to 'application/json' resolved the issue, now all data is properly deserialized on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you really think its something wrong with the actual deserialization then I would recommend downloading the source code from github and trying to create failing unit tests. If you think its with the json deserialization then download the ServiceStack.Text project. Otherwise you should download the main ServiceStack project. Reading the existing unit tests are quite informative to how the entire project works.

However, **chances are it is invalid json notation**. It is often useful to reverse engineer the json by comparing the results from Serializing your DTO to what you are actually passing into the ajax call.

**Updated:** Your json should look like this:

```
{"Caller":{"Name":"John Doe"}}
```

The easy way to check this is to do the following:

```
var r = new MyRequest() {Caller = new Caller() {Name = "John Doe"}};
var json = r.ToJson();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually don't think there's something wrong, I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong. I certainly don't think there's anything wrong with deserialization, it's working when I simply deserialize the body. What I am trying to figure out is what is different when the objects are mapped to request objects by servicestack, and when the body is deserialized manually. Hope that makes sense. If not, I can provide code samples.

Comment: I think it would help if you provide specific code examples. It will provide more help for others in the future too.